# mkimage doesn't add public key to .dtb file

Tags: bootloader, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am trying to make a verified boot on beaglebone black by following the documentation

https://github.com/01org/edison-u-boot/blob/master/doc/uImage.FIT/beaglebone_vboot.txt

when i run the command to put public key into .dtb file

```
mkimage -f sign.its -K am335x-boneblack.dtb -k keys -r image.fit
```

I get the output

```
FIT description: Beaglebone black
Created:         Fri Mar 24 18:47:51 2017
 Image 0 (kernel@1)
  Description:  unavailable
  Created:      Fri Mar 24 18:47:51 2017
  Type:         Kernel Image
  Compression:  lzo compressed
  Data Size:    8490316 Bytes = 8291.32 KiB = 8.10 MiB
  Architecture: ARM
  OS:           Linux
  Load Address: 0x80008000
  Entry Point:  0x80008000
  Hash algo:    sha1
  Hash value:   9a390ee3c02c5bddc7b191d5cbe107991522a6d7
 Image 1 (fdt@1)
  Description:  beaglebone-black
  Created:      Fri Mar 24 18:47:51 2017
  Type:         Flat Device Tree
  Compression:  uncompressed
  Data Size:    38894 Bytes = 37.98 KiB = 0.04 MiB
  Architecture: ARM
  Hash algo:    sha1
  Hash value:   249ca75de41f5202fae334253bd153666f60b7dc
 Default Configuration: 'conf@1'
 Configuration 0 (conf@1)
  Description:  unavailable
  Kernel:       kernel@1
  FDT:          fdt@1
```

But unfortunately there is no such a field like signature or rsa in my .dtb file when i read it with fdtdump.

Here is my .its file:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    description = "Beaglebone black";
    #address-cells = <1>;

    images {
        kernel@1 {
            data = /incbin/("zImage.lzo");
            type = "kernel";
            arch = "arm";
            os = "linux";
            compression = "lzo";
            load = <0x80008000>;
            entry = <0x80008000>;
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
        fdt@1 {
            description = "beaglebone-black";
            data = /incbin/("am335x-boneblack.dtb");
            type = "flat_dt";
            arch = "arm";
            compression = "none";
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "conf@1";
        conf@1 {
            kernel = "kernel@1";
            fdt = "fdt@1";
            signature@1 {
                algo = "sha1,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "dev";
                sign-images = "fdt", "kernel";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

also in keys folder i have dev.key and dev.crt files.

thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though there's no error message, mkimage does not support that function if CONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE in U-Boot's .config  is not set.

Answer (score 0):

as it says in: https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#uboot/doc/uImage.FIT/signature.txt

### Public Key Storage

In order to verify an image that has been signed with a public key we need to
have a trusted public key. This cannot be stored in the signed image, since
it would be easy to alter. For this implementation we choose to store the
public key in U-Boot's control FDT (using CONFIG_OF_CONTROL).

Regards, Steve